# Logging CSV Data Import

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csv, import

I'm working to create a web-based C# application that takes CSV files, parses them, and formats them into a clean table... I think I can handle parsing the data by commas, however, I would like to be able to log the process.

This project was assigned to me by my new employer which wants to migrate toward a .net web application, and he described it as:

"The application needs to handle logging the file import process."

I'm not entirely sure what he expects in regards to that. I would think that the IDE would do that in itself. In any other regard, maybe writing a log to a file of record of import is what he is implying.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not ask clarification from your new employer instead of asking us to take a guess?

Comment: 1rst. Perhaps the question is for your employer? "logging the file import process" ?? Log the strat and the end of each file process for witch user? Or Log erronous line( malformed or invalid data)? For erronous line you invalidate the file or the line? What happend to the erronous line does some one ever look at them to fix them? Does the user care?

Comment: I should ask the employer what they desire. It's a tiny aspect of a larger project and is more of a test than anything. My thoughts are somebody VB C# data import experience might know why I would, or a way I could record it into a file and make an impression on my boss.

Comment: If he want to know log each line well it's not a log it's the result table.

Comment: And by the way "I would think that the IDE would do that in itself.". IDE is a tool like any tool it does only what you ask them to do.

Comment: Exactly what I'm thinking... the log is the table itself. It really makes no sense to me whatsoever. Maybe he wants a timestamp? Not sure. I mean VB explicitly.

Comment: created date, modification date, user id+ original file name, Importer ID. But thats quickto fix and not important things. Adding a column to a table is not a big deal.

Comment: Of course not. He was clear on the presentation of the table as it is a web application. Perhaps creating a separate table with other information would count as a "log?"

Comment: The only things I could think to log with this are date, time and completion. There is no user environment yet.

Comment: I made a chat for further disscus https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179517/questions-52197415

Comment: I cannot participate in the chat, but the CSV files given has much more commas then needed in the file (so kind of broken data) and also has more data than needed listed in the table requested.